# How can I pass variable in draw.text() function instead of string?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, raspberry-pi3

I want to pass integer value instead of String, say a = 45, but it's not working!

```
import Image
import ImageDraw
import ImageFont


width = disp.width
height = disp.height
image = Image.new('1', (width, height))

font = ImageFont.load_default()
a = 45

draw.text((x, top), a ,  font=font, fill=255)
draw.text((x, top+20), 'World!', font=font, fill=255)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast a to a string using  `draw.text((x, top), str(a) ,  font=font, fill=255)`.

You could also use `a = '45'` defining it as a string. However I would advise against this as you may want to use it as an integer before drawing it.

Comment: but I am getting real-time data in this variable, so I can't make it string

Comment: Using str(a) will take the real time value of a and return a str representation of it, it will not affect the value of the variable a so should work with real time data.

Comment: Thanks! working fine :)